# puppeteer не работает в безголовом режиме с userDataDir

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, headless

Я хочу запустить браузер хром с помощью puppeteer, указав ему папку куда сохранять все данные с сайта (сеансы, куки и так далее):

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    headless: false,
    args: ['--window-size=1200,860'],
    userDataDir: "./user_data"
});
```

И все отлично работает, но стоит только включить безголовый режим:

```
headless: true
```

Как браузер просто зависает и не запускается. Но если убрать:

```
userDataDir: "./user_data"
```

то браузер работает в безголовом режиме.

Как заставить работать браузер в безголовом режиме с `userDataDir: "./user_data"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, это старый баг: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3453

Чтобы обойти, попробуйте абсолютный путь (на Windows с разделителем `\\`) или `path.resolve('user_data')`.